# Multibinding Command Parameters

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm-light, multibinding, relaycommand

So I have a context menu for each individual listview item and the listview is bound to a user list.  The context menu has a sub-menu that is bound to an observable collection of user statuses.  I want to be able to pass the user id from the list view AND the new status ID from the context menu to my update command parameter.  I just looked in to MultiBindings and believe this may be a good, long term solution that I can use elsewhere.  Here is some code:

**ListView from User View:**

```
<ListView Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding UserList}" SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="Menu" DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
            <MenuItem Name="UserID" Header="{Binding UserID}"/>
                <Separator></Separator>
                    <MenuItem Header="Status" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.UserStatus, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                              DisplayMemberPath="Name" Name="StatusID">
                        <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.UpdateDriverStatus, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
                                <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}" />
                            </Style>

                        </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <MenuItem.CommandParameter>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiBindConverter}">
                                <Binding ElementName="DriverID"></Binding>
                                <Binding ElementName="StatusID"></Binding>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </MenuItem.CommandParameter>                        </MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListView.Resources>

            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource Menu}" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemContainerTemplate>

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}" >

                            </TextBlock>
                </ItemContainerTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

**User VM:**

```
public class UsersPanelVM : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<UserPanelItem> UserList { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<UserStatusList> UserStatus { get; set; }

    private readonly IUserService _userService;
    public IUserService UserService { get { return this._userService; } }

    public UsersPanelVM(IUserService userService)
    {
        this._userService = userService;

        var model = this.UserService.GetUsers();
        this.UserList = model.Users;
        var statusmodel = this.UserService.GetUserStatus();
        this.UserStatus = statusmodel.UserStatus;

        this.UpdateUserStatus = new RelayCommand<UserStatusList>((s) => UpdateStatus(1,s));
    }

    //The 1, above, is hard coded to test the method call, but ideally that should be the selected UserID

    private void UpdateStatus(int ID, UserStatusList s)
    {

    }

    public RelayCommand<UserStatusList> UpdateUserStatus { get; private set; }

}
```

I'm pretty sure I am 100% lost at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is not necessary as i already mentioned in your other question because you have **all the information except the new status** in your object model.

   Move the command and the `UpdateStatus` method into the `UserPanelItem`'s class, which also should hold your ID, then you just need to change the command to:

   ```
   new RelayCommand(param => UpdateStatus(ID, (UserStatusList)param))
   ```
2. If you really want to do it this way: You again set the `CommandParameter` of the parent `MenuItem` whose Command will never even be used, move it to the `CommandParameter`-`Setter`'s `Value` in the container style, i.e.

   ```
   <Setter Property="CommandParameter">
       <Setter.Value>
           <MultiBinding ...>
               ....
   ```